# Image from camera get lost when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-camera, orientation, crop

i was working on a app where user can take pic from the camera, crop it and then this pic will be shown in an imageView.

The problem is if i change orientation of camera from what it started and click it then i am not able to load image for cropping.

I have tried `android:configChanges` and `savedInstanceState()` on my activity containing imageView but it didnt worked out.

how this problem can be resolved???

Comment: you can easily avoid that by setting on your manifest, inside your activity `android:screenOrientation="portrait" >` (or landscape)

Comment: thanks but this is making my activity restricted ... is there not any way to achieve without fixing orientation???